# from array.sort() to compareTo()

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparable, compareto

I felt like I didn't make my question clear enough in the other thread so I'm using this one to narrow down what I'm trying to ask.

Say I'm trying to sort an array containing two tweets by the name of authors:

```
   public class Tweet implements Comparable {
   private String mName;

  public Tweet(String name) {
   mName = name;
   }

     public int compareTo(Object obj) {
        Tweet tempArrays = [Tweet] arrays;
         return mName.compareTo(tempArrays.mName);
   }

    }
```

Then override compareTo() and then

```
  Tweet new tweetOne = tweet("Andy")
  Tweet new tweetTwo = tweet("Bob")
  Array[] arrays = {tweetOne, tweetTwo}
  Array.sort(arrays);
```

Does the last line roughly translate to:

```
    return "Andy".compareTo("Bob");
```

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: is this a typing mistake   `public class implements Comparable Tweet ` ? because it should be like   `public class Tweet  implements Comparable`

Answer (score 1):

Your class shall look like this

```
  public class Tweet implements Comparable {
   private String mName;

  public Tweet(String name) {
     mName = name;
   }

   public int compareTo(Object obj) {
    Tweet tempTweet = (Tweet) obj;
     return mName.compareTo(tempTweet.mName);
   }
 }
```

And then you can sort your array like this:

```
Tweet[] tweets = new Tweet[]{ Tweet("Andy"),Tweet("Bob")};

Arrays.sort(tweets);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I'm trying to understanding how overriding the compareTo() method works though, not manually sorting the tweets :|

Comment: When You call Arrays.sort it compares objects as per comparable implementation, so control goes to compareTo method and it works

Comment: @kshatriiya: Here's the [OpenJDK source code for Arrays](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java).  Start with the sort(Object[], int, int, Comparator)  method, go on to the mergeSort(Object[], Object[], int, int, int, Comparator)  method, and keep following the code until you're satisfied that the Java developers implemented sort correctly.